# Macro architecture to set up sum until going into multiple variables

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I am trying to create an excel macro that will add the values while they are positive  into a variable say "A". When it changes into negative, add all the negative values into "B". When it changes into positive again, add all the values into "C". When it goes into negative again, add all the negative into "D"... and so on.

for example if my data is:
`Data-> (0,0,1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,0,0,-1)`
I want the output to be

```
A=1
B=-1
C=2
D=-3
```

I am unsure how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the values in an array, it's a just a simple matter of keeping track of the current sign to determine when you need to switch:

```
Private Sub DemoCode()
    Dim values() As Variant
    values = Array(0, 0, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 0, 0, -1)

    Dim sign As Long, i As Long
    Dim current As Long, results As New Collection
    sign = 1
    For i = LBound(values) To UBound(values)
        '0 is "signless".
        If values(i) <> 0 Then
            'Did the sign change?
            If values(i) \ Abs(values(i)) <> sign Then
                'Store the accumulated result.
                results.Add current
                'Flip the sentinel sign.
                sign = -sign
                'Reset the accumulator.
                current = 0
            End If
        End If
        current = current + values(i)
    Next I
    'Add the last result.
    results.Add current

    Dim result As Variant
    For Each result In results
        Debug.Print result
    Next
End Sub
```